# PHP Search Highlighting Undefined Error Set Error

Tags: php, regex, arrays

I have a search form and i highlight the keyword if it is within the body of the any one of the pages. What i'm facing is sort of case insensitive problem. When user searchs for "SearchMe", and the if the body containts the exact string "SearchMe", it shows it highlighted well. But when user writes "searchme", it gives undefined offset : 1 error for the function and just outputs and highlights the query, plus doesn't remove the one in the body, so think like it gots duplicated. Why does it happen and how can i fix that?

```
function getSearchResult($str, $query, $numOfWordToAdd) {
list($before, $after) = explode($query, $str);

$before = rtrim($before);
$after  = ltrim($after);

$beforeArray = array_reverse(explode(" ", $before));
$afterArray  = explode(" ", $after);

$countBeforeArray = count($beforeArray);
$countAfterArray  = count($afterArray);

$beforeString = "";
if($countBeforeArray < $numOfWordToAdd) {
    $beforeString = implode(' ', $beforeArray);
}
else {
    for($i = 0; $i < $numOfWordToAdd; $i++) {
        $beforeString = $beforeArray[$i] . ' ' . $beforeString;
    }
}

$afterString = "";
if($countAfterArray < $numOfWordToAdd) {
    $afterString = implode(' ', $afterArray);
}
else {
    for($i = 0; $i < $numOfWordToAdd; $i++) {
        $afterString = $afterString . $afterArray[$i] . ' ';
    }
}

$string = $beforeString . ' <span class="underline"> ' . $query . ' </span> ' . ' ' . $afterString;

return $string;
}
```

How i call this :

```
echo getSearchResult($result->body,$keywords,30);
```

Comment: "searchMe" is different than "searchme". (Case-sensitive).
Consider "lower-casing" the query and the "body" and then setting the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

As you have included RegExp's in your tags, while not just using them?
This should do the trick (untested):

```
// The 'i' flag at the end of the regexp makes the search case insensitive
$regexp = "#(" . $query . ")#i"; 
$replacement = '<span class="underline">$2</span>';

$string = preg_replace ($regexp, $replacement, $result->body)
```

Note that if $query includes #, you either have to escape them or use another char (any char is valid) to surround the regexp.

If you only want to highlight the first occurrence, add 1 as a 4th parameter to preg_replace.

[Edit]: Forgot to mention: when you got multiple keywords to search for, use this:
`$query = implode('|', $keywords);`
and use the resulting string as query in the code above.

Comment: still gives undefined offset 1 in list($before, $after) = explode($query, $str);

Comment: My code completely replaces your function. There is no need for any explode.